# Image displaying wrong

Tags: html, css, image, padding

I want to create some neat circular buttons for a user interface, but I can't use divs because the links won't work then.

I've got a rounded image with the *border-radius* property, which is 50 pixels wide and tall. The dimensions of the image inside was decreased to 30 pixels to look nicer, and a 10 pixel *padding* was brought in to make a total of 50 pixels, not counting the border.

However, I want the ***border-radius*** applied only on the border, and not the image within. Is there any way to get around this problem w/o the use of a div?

#### CSS

```
img.userinterface {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;}
```

A basic html if you want to check it out:

#### HTML

```
<img class="userinterface" src="xyz">
```

Comment: Why can't you use a div?

Comment: It is being made on an online website creator and unfortunately it won't recognize an <a> as a link if there is a <div> inside of it.

Comment: That online creator need an update, as of HTML5 an anchor/link is now allowed to have a div inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the extra `img` when you can make the link round as is

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff url(http://lorempizza.com/100/100/) center center;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
a:hover {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is that the `border-radius` isn't taking into account the `padding`, try using `box-sizing: border-box;` and see if that makes a difference in how the image is displayed.